# List of EF objects not being sorted correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sorting

For some reason, my list of EF objects aren't being sorted correctly. I'm trying to sort by date, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Code:

```
onQuotes.Sort((d1, d2) =>
{
    return d1.WonDt.Value.CompareTo(d2.WonDt.Value);
});
```

Comment: What is `onQuotes` for a type?

Comment: You know you are not doing the sort in the database, but in .NET, don't you?

Comment: `onQuotes = List<TblQuote>` ... `TblQuote` is the EF object.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to sort it for a calculation I'm doing. I know it's not being sorted in the DB.

Comment: Wait, is `WonDt` implemented via a nullable type perchance?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in that delegate and inspect the values of `d1.WonDt.Value` and `d2.WonDt.Value`. Do those values even differ?

Comment: Yes. They are all different. Usually by a couple of minutes.

Comment: In the database, `WonDt` can be null, but in the database diagram, it's set to `Nullable - (None)`. Not sure what the difference is, that setting has always confused me.

Comment: `null`s will baffle your sort.

Comment: @DoctorOreo - if nulls are actually materialized the hydration will throw an exception.  This feature is kept, because i some cases the developer knows that only non-null objects will be materialized (maybe by adding a where clause for Active Records, or some department = z).  It can actually be quite useful for the model to skew from the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this bit does anything for you:

```
        onQuotes.Sort((d1, d2) =>
        {
            if (d1.WonDt.HasValue && d2.WonDt.HasValue)
            {
                return d1.WonDt.Value.CompareTo(d2.WonDt.Value);
            }

            if (!d1.WonDt.HasValue && !d2.WonDt.HasValue)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return d1.WonDt.HasValue ? 1 : -1;
        });
```

or more compactly written:

```
        onQuotes.Sort((d1, d2) => d1.WonDt.HasValue && d2.WonDt.HasValue
            ? d1.WonDt.Value.CompareTo(d2.WonDt.Value)
            : (!d1.WonDt.HasValue && !d2.WonDt.HasValue
                ? 0
                : (d1.WonDt.HasValue ? 1 : -1)));
```